# C: Evaluation of pointer arihmetic: When is an operation done?

Tags: c, pointers, math

```
void add( int a, int b) {
   a += b;
  }
 void sub( int *a, int* b) {
  *a -= *b; }
 void mul( int a, int *b) {
    a *= *b;
  }
  void div( int *a, int b) {
    *a /= b; }
  int a = 2, b = 3;
  sub( &a, &a );
  add(  a,  b );
  div( &a,  b );
  mul(  b, &a );
  div( &b,  b );
  add(  b,  a );
  printf( "%d\n", a ); 
  printf( "%d\n", b );
```

Why isn't a = 1 and b = 2, instead a = 0 and b = 1.
Can anyone explain to me what *, &, so what pointer, in this code is the reason for doing an operation?

Comment: `add` doesn't take a pointer. Is that correct?

Comment: There's no "pointer arithmetic" in this code. *Pointer arithmetic* has a very specific meaning in C. Here you have pointers and have arithmetic, but no *pointer arithmetic*. Also, your `add` and `mul` functions are effectively no-ops that don't do anything at all. That is why in the end a = 0 and b = 1.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger and see what what happens at each line.

Comment: It would be very little trouble to post a compilable program that includes the required library and wraps the illegal code in `main`. Please refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `add` and `mul` do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In general this has nothing to do with pointer arithmetic. It's about calling the function correctly, i.e. when to use a pointer and when to use an integer.

Since you want to change `a` and leave `b` unchanged, all your functions shall have the form:

```
void function(int* const a, const int b) {…}
```

Since `a` is "passed as a pointer" you can change the value of `a` using the syntax `*a = …`. Since the pointer is `const` the pointer itself can't be changed. As `b` is never to be changed, it's best to pass it as a `const`.

If you change all function in that way, correct the function body accordingly and also the way you call the functions, you'll be fine.

**example**

```
void add( int* const a, const int b) {
   *a += b;
}


int a = 0;

add(&a, 42);
```